# how to read file names under directory(local file system/hdfs) using flink java api

Tags: filesystems, export-to-csv, apache-flink

I am new to Flink . Actually I am trying to read files and csv conversion through flink java api.

As per our requirement .
a) Need to pass folder as a input argument , output argument as a csv file name
b) Need to read files from local file system/HDFS 
c) Write the same data to csv

My code:

```
public class WriteToCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
        File dir = new File("C://");
        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
              paths.add(f.getName());
        }
        DataSet<String> data = env.fromCollection(paths).rebalance();

        DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = 
                    // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
                    data.flatMap(new MySplitter()).groupBy(0).sum(1);

        System.out.println(" data -:"+data);
        data.print();
        counts.writeAsCsv("C://new.csv");
    }
}


class MySplitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
        // normalize and split the line into words
        String[] tokens = value.split("\\W+");

        // emit the pairs
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.length() > 0) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(token, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get the file names (data.print()) . but csv is not creating ,no exception in the server console.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why nothing is written to the csv in your code is that you don't call `env.execute()` after `counts.writeAsCsv("C://new.csv");`

To improve your code further you can use `env.readTextFile(path)` which accepts path to a directory and reads all files in that directory producing record for each line.

Comment: DataSet and DataStream programs differ in their `print()` behavior. DataSet programs trigger an execution when `print()` is called and write the result to the stdout of the client that submitted the program. DataStream programs do not start the program (this requires `execute()`) and print to the stdout of the worked.

Comment: Yes I know, but in the provided example `print()` is called before `writeAsCsv` so I believe it is printed well, but the output is not written to the csv.